# Toad connectivity issue with oracle 11g

Tags: database, toad

I am facing one issue while connecting Toad with oracle 11g.
ORA-28547: connection to server failed, probable Oracle Net admin error

Please find require details as follow.

1.tnsnames.ora

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: F:\app\god\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.7)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl.168.1.7)
    )
  )
```

2. sqlnet.ora

   ## sqlnet.ora Network Configuration File: F:\app\god\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\sqlnet.ora

   ## Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

   ## This file is actually generated by netca. But if customers choose to

   ## install "Software Only", this file wont exist and without the native

   ## authentication, they will not be able to connect to the database on NT.

   SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NONE)

   NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (EZCONNECT, TNSNAMES)

   ADR_BASE = F:\app\god\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\log

3.listener.ora

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: F:\app\god\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = F:\app\god\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:F:\app\god\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr11.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.7)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = F:\app\god
```

also let me know what host,port,service_id/sid needs to be provided in toad while connecting this db. Both are installed on  my same laptop

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but couldn't find the solution yet.
Yesterday TOAD worked fine, but today im getting this error.

I think it must be something with TOAD, since I have no problem with SQL Developer.

EDIT: I solved the problem by restarting my computer.